# Found a Jamma cabled cabinet. Can I replace the board with a multigame one?

Tags: emulation, arcade

I found an arcade cabinet. The seller told me he cabled it as a Jamma standard. It has an old CRT monitor and a pcb with one game running on it. I would like to replace this board with a multigame one.

Searching around, I found out the [Pandora Boxes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019RITWKO) or some [60 in 1](https://www.ebay.com/p/Arcade-Classics-60-in-1-PCB-W-cga-VGA-JAMMA-Vertical-Ac708/24010195970?iid=253272615994) boards. I guess these are some kind of emulators, am I right?

I read around that, at least the first ones, are chinese clones and might need some extra cable work. I believe someone referred them as "CHAMMA". I noticed these cartridge have a VGA output. I did not see anything like that in the cabinet. Is this for newer setup?

I would like to know if these boards are "plug and play" or not. 
If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pandora's Box worked quite well.

I just had to attach the JAMMA connector to the cartridge, ignoring the VGA port. 
VGA port can be used to attach it to a monitor or a projector.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with those specific boards, but in general you do need an adapter for the monitor with newer boards.